# Mapping requests to RestController with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly, spring-rest

Good evening to all,

I have been learning spring boot recently and I am trying to develop a simple restful application using spring rest and spring boot.

So I am deploying the app on WildFly application server and I am using a coded application context configuration. My problem is that the app starts normally, no errors or bugs, but when trying to invoke the service nothing happens, seems like the request is not mapped to the controller. Can someone please explain to me how the mapping is done in this case? 
Here are some peaces of code that may seem helpful for solving the problem:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>Restfull application</display-name>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>
   org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
  </listener-class>
 </listener>

<!-- Configure ContextLoaderListener to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
     instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
  <param-value>
       org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
  </param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Configuration locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
   fully-qualified @Configuration classes. Fully-qualified packages may also be
   specified for component-scanning -->
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>configuration.ApplicationContext</param-value>
 </context-param>

</web-app>
```

ApplicationContext.java:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"DAL","domains","services","controllers","configuration"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class ApplicationContext extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Autowired
Environment environment;
private static Class<ApplicationContext> applicationClass = ApplicationContext.class;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(applicationClass);
}

@Bean(name = "datasource")
public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
    dataSource.setValidationQuery(environment.getProperty("validationQuery"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("*");

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",environment.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql",environment.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",environment.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(this.sessionFactoryBean().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public GenericRepositoryImpl personRepo() {
    GenericRepositoryImpl<Person,Integer> personRepo = new GenericRepositoryImpl<Person,Integer>();
    return personRepo;
}

@Bean
public PersonServiceImpl personService() {
    return new PersonServiceImpl();
}
}
```

ContactsController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/listAll")
public class ContactsController {

@Autowired
private IPersonService personService;


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Person> getAllContacts() {
    System.out.println("******** I'am here *********");
    List<Person> contacts = personService.findAllContacts();
    return contacts;
}
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>TP2ArchitecturesLogicielles</groupId>
<artifactId>Activite3RestfulWebService</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>Activite3RestfulWebService Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.5</mysql.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->

    <!-- Hibernate validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->

    <!-- Spring Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Commons tools -->

    <!-- Commons pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Commons DBCP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySql connector -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for being too verbose.

Comment: Remove the web.xml... In your `ApplicationClass` replace `@Configuration` with `@SpringBootApplication` and remove `@EnableTransactionManagement` and the `@PropertySource` annotations.

Comment: nothing changed still the same behaviour

Comment: Did you also make the annotation changes?

Comment: Also which URL are you calling?

Comment: When changing the annotations the application doesn't start anymore and it throws exceptions: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener

Comment: and I am using the /listAll when calling

Comment: That exception points you to the fact that you are missing some dependencies or have conflicting once... Please add your pom.

Comment: alright I've added the pom in the question

Comment: Remove the `org.springframework` dependencies, those are pulled in by the starter already. The only one you need is `spring-orm` and you don't need a version for that as that is already managed for you. The same applies to hibernate and commons-dbcp dependencies. Boot already manages those for you. And remove the javax.servlet dependency as well as Spring boot manages that also.

Comment: still having the same exception

Comment: You should also remove the versions from the `properties` element else you will force boot to use a different version which isn't compatible.

Comment: works perfectly! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are not correct.

First you have a `web.xml` which isn't needed next to that your `web.xml` is for a 2.5 version of the Servlet API not 3.0. Which disables the `ServletContainerInitializer` support of Servlet 3.0. Which effectively disables the picking up of your `ApplicationContext` class. Instead just remove it.

Next your dependencies, Spring Boot already does automatic management of those and with that it makes sure you get versions of frameworks you need. Regarding the dependencies Spring Boot provides so called starter projects (which you use) which already pull in the different dependencies so no need to add them again. Furthermore Spring Boot already has dependency set for different libraries.

To fix your pom

1. Remove the `<properties>` section
2. Clean up your dependencies.

You should have the following `pom.xml`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>TP2ArchitecturesLogicielles</groupId>
<artifactId>Activite3RestfulWebService</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>Activite3RestfulWebService Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->

    <!-- Hibernate validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Commons DBCP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySql connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

There was a lot of stuff in there not needed and Spring Boot already manages versions and correct dependencies.

Now the final part has to do with your `ApplicationContext` class it isn't a full blown Spring Boot class. There is no auto-configuration enabled. Either add `@EnableAutoConfiguration` or simply replace `@Configuration` with `@SpringBootApplication`. Spring Boot will automatically enable transactions so you can remove the `@EnableTransactionManagement` and the `application.properties` is also already loaded so the `@PropertySource` should go also.

Also judging from the `@ComponentScan` the `ApplicationContext` is in some root package. Which would also mean that can go also. Leaving only the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationContext extends SpringBootServletInitializer { ... }

Also tip for the future use [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io) to setup your project. Just a few clicks and you get a proper pom and pre configured `Application` class.